# Grouping into an array

Tags: c#, javascript, json, encoding

This seems like it should be fairly easy, but, for some reason my brain is not cooperating.

I have a simple method that calls this:

```
return Json.Encode(
    Models
    .GroupBy(e => e.Gender)
    .Select(g => new {
        Gender = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count()
    }).ToArray()
);
```

This produces the following JSON:

```
[{"Gender":"Male","Count":2},{"Gender":"No Answer","Count":1}]
```

However, I want the JSON object to look like this:

```
[
    ['Male', 2],
    ['No Answer', 1]
]
```

I've tried using a Tuple and Dictionary to no avail.  I'm sure I will be kicking myself once this is answered.

Comment: What you want it to look like is actually not JSON, it's an array of arrays.

Comment: @MarcMarta which is perfectly valid json...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
return Json.Encode(
    Models
    .GroupBy(e => e.Gender)
    .Select(g => new object[] { g.Key, g.Count() })
    .ToArray()
);
```

You want an array of arrays, so simply create arrays.

Comment: Argh.  I tried something similar to this, but, my syntax was incorrect.  This works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) for this. These provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly define a type first.

So, just skip your `Gender` and `Count` properties from your Select Expression.

```
return Json.Encode(Models
                     .GroupBy(e => e.Gender)
                     .Select(g => new object[] { g.Key, g.Count()})
                     .ToArray());
```

Notice that

- If you do not specify member names in the anonymous type, the compiler gives the anonymous type members the same name as the property being used to initialize them.
- You must provide a name for a property that is being initialized with an expression(in your case `Gender` and `Count`)